# "Spain's prince" or "Spain's prince's"

Tags: possessives, phrase-choice

> 1. The king underwrote the journey of Spain's prince.
> 2. The king underwrote the journey of Spain's prince's.

We have a double possessive here, we are referring to the journey of the prince of Spain. How do we express that in a sentence? If I were refer, say, to a house that belongs to may uncle I would say "the house of my uncle's". For this reason I think the second sentence is correct but it sounds a bit odd. Can you help me?

Comment: People don't say "Spain's prince", they say "the prince of Spain". [See Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prince+of+Spain%2CSpain%27s+prince&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). This may be why the sentences sound odd.

Comment: @Peter: But there's nothing unusual about [Iceland's prime minister](http://www.scmp.com/news/china/article/1216964/gay-wife-icelands-prime-minister-visits-beijing-university). Grammatically speaking, I mean. I must admit I was surprised after choosing that particular leader at random to discover that his independently globe-trotting wife is gay!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Small correction — *her* globe-trotting wife. And your link is about Iceland's prime minister's wife's visit to China, which is a triple possessive.

Comment: @Peter: Ooops! I didn't read beyond the headline. It's a bizarre headline though, given that obviously *both* partners are gay. I'm not sure "wife" makes a lot of sense there either, but I suppose that's because it's a Chinese newspaper (which may well affect the phrasing grammatically, politically, *and* sociologically).

Comment: ...also, *Iceland's prime minister's wife's visit* involves a "true and necessary" triple possessive, whereas *the visit of Iceland's prime minister's wife's* would be a superfluous ***quadruple*** possessive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Out of curiosity, why wouldn't “wife” make sense? Woman + spouse = wife, no?

Comment: @Tyler: She's no longer in office, but at the time of this question, [Jóhanna Sigurðardóttir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3hanna_Sigur%C3%B0ard%C3%B3ttir) was the Icelandic Prime Minister, and she's gay. Admittedly, I don't know many lesbians in long-term relationships, but I certainly never heard any of them refer to their partner as "wife". It would seem like a slightly odd usage to me, but maybe some such couples *do* both accept the designation for themselves *and* apply it to their partner.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It wouldn't make sense in every long-term relationship, just ones where the two people are married, as in the case in question.

Comment: @Tyler: I think you miss my point. Although I don't know many *lesbian* couples, I've known many people in long-term male+male relationships, and *none* of them ever refer to their partner as "husband". Nor am I expecting that to change now that gay *marriage* (a *religious* ceremony, as opposed to the equivalent secular "civil partnership" which we've had for years) has just been introduced in the UK. Actually, I hadn't realised gay marriage had already been introduced in Iceland back in 2010. But of course they speak Icelandic, so they wouldn't use the words *wife/husband* anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The double possessive is much more likely with *pronouns*, as discussed in [this related ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/50588/2637) (it's normally *friend of mine/yours/his/ours/theirs/etc.*, rather than *of me/you/him/us/them*).

With actual nouns, it's largely a matter of personal choice whether to use a *friend of Peter* or *of Peter's*. Some pedants might object that the possessive apostrophe is redundant - but the usage has long been commonplace, and it would be perverse to say it's been "wrong" all the time.

Having said that, I doubt anyone would seriously endorse OP's ***triple*** possessive *of Spain's prince's* (which wouldn't be any better as *of the prince of Spain's*). It's just stylistically clumsy.

Comment: The journey of the prince of Spain is a triple possessive? The are just the possesions, the Spain possessses the prince and the prince posseses a visit..

Comment: @ Pedro: *The journey **of** the prince **of** Spain* is just two perfectly normal possessive **of**'s (which could be expressed as *Spain's prince's journey*, though that's a bit clumsy). The usage in your title *(the journey of Spain's prince's)* involves a ***third*** (superfluous) possessive (the apostrophe after *prince*), which I assume is what you're asking about here. But idiomatically, when people talk about the "double possessive", they just mean the use of both *of **and** apostrophe* for the same "possessive relationship", regardless of any other possessive relationships there are.

Comment: Is there a reason you're saying "Spain's prince" vs. "the Spanish prince?" "Spain's prince" sounds highly unnatural to me.

Comment: @Greg: There are two slightly different usages involved here, as illustrated by *Australia's Kylie Minogue is well-known all around the world* and *Britain's Prime Minister is well-known* (the first categorises *the one-and-only* Kylie as Australian, the second tells us *which particular* Prime Minister is being referenced). For many of us OP's specific noun *prince* falls somewhere between those two usages.

Comment: That's certainly *why* it sounds unnatural. "Spain's prince" implies there is only one. Could make sense in context, I suppose. If every nation sent one prince to a contest and the king chose to fund Spain's prince's proposal. But I suspect that's not the actual context of the sentence. He probably really does want "The king underwrote the Spanish prince's journey." We just can't tell at this point.

Comment: @Greg: True, we just can't tell. But I'm guessing OP is really trying to get to grips with the apparently superfluous possessive apostrophe in, say, *"That journey of Peter's was unnecessary"*.

Comment: The more possessives you have, the more unlikely it is for somebody to add the superfluous one. *That journey of Peter's"* sounds fine, but I can't imagine anybody using the final *"'s"* in *"the visit of the Prime Minister of Iceland's wife's"*.

Comment: @Peter: Quite. It's a matter of "more unlikely" rather than some hard-and-fast rule. But there does seem to be something else involved in the specific case of the "superfluous" possessive apostrophe in ***of X's***. I find it more or less "necessary" in my *journey of Peter's* example, but highly undesirable/incorrect in, say, *"All I could hear was the voice of Peter's"*.