# Do we need 's in "I'm a friend of Stephen's."

Tags: grammar

> I'm a friend of Stephen**'s**.

It's British English, period: around 1970's.

Do we need that **'s** at the end of the name? I can see why it is there when you say, for instance, "I was at **Stephen's**." Here you omit something; you can put something after **Stephens's** and complete the sentence: "I was at **Stephen's** *home*."

But in the first sentence you cannot put anything after **Stephen's**.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/the-king-underwrote-the-journey-of-spains-prince-or-the-king-underwrote-the and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of

Also, I found these very helpful: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/double-possessives, http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/337101944?r=796100154#796100154

Comment: It's not wrong, but I'm not sure if you need it.

Comment: You could say "I am going to my cousin's." There is an implicit word, there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are using 'friend'.  If you are referring to a group of people that are collectively friends of Stephen, then you do need the possessive apostrophe.  In that case the *omitted something* you refer to is shown by the translated 'I am one of Stephen's friends'.

If you are referring to your friendliness with a person called Stephen, then you don't.

For a similar (but more obvious) example, consider

```
I have a picture of Stephen
```

vs

```
I have a picture of Stephen's
```

In the first you have a picture whose content is the image of Stephen.  In the second you have a picture that belongs to Stephen.

Comment: If Stephen has three friends, and I am one of them, then do I need the possessive apostrophe?

Comment: @J.R. *Need* is debatable, but I think it's common. For example "Any friend of Stephen's is a friend of mine!" That's a common phrase, and the 's is there. Without the apostrophe I'd prefer "I am a friend to Stephen" rather than "I am a friend of Stephen". (The *to* version sounds a bit strange/formal/something I can't place, but it seems more logical than "...of Stephen". Like you might say "He was a friend to many" rather than "he was a friend of many". Sounds a bit like a eulogy, but I still favor the "to" version without the apostrophe. /rambling

Comment: @JR, Still depends.  If you are talking about the group that is *possessed* (in the sense of the possessive apostrophe) by Stephen - which you are a member of - then yes. If you are talking about your friendship with Stephen and the fact that he has two other friends exists, but isn't relevant, then no.

Comment: @WendiKidd example uses of 'friend of' include *Amicus Curiae* - friends of the court, and the much anecdoted *a friend of a friend told me ...*. I don't think 'to' would work in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

On another forum we have looked more closely  into the problem of  "a friend of Stephan's" which seems to be a very old case form and in the meantime rather a ballast.
Via Google Ngrams and the BNC we have found out that you can say  a friend of Stephan's or a friend of Stephan.

So grammars that have a rule that in certain cases one has to use the of-genitive with 's are no longer up-to-date. Language is changing.

Comment: In some cases, you still have to use the of-genitive with *'s*. For example, you need to use the *'s* in *a picture of Stephen's*, unless you want to say that Stephen is depicted in the picture. The same is true for other ambiguous cases like *"a vision of Johanna's"*, *"a movie of Stephen's"*, *"a dream of Martin's"*, *"news of Amelia's"*, and so on. But you don't need to use it if there's not another interpretation of *"of Stephen"*.

Comment: Another case where you need the of-genetive with *'s*: *"a gift of Stephen's"* can't be replaced by *"a gift of Stephen"* (unless Stephen himself is the gift).