# why don't we use "-'s" for some nouns that belong to other nouns?

Tags: apostrophe

I was wondering why we do not use `'s` for some nouns that belong to other nouns? 
For example:

> **book cover** or **book's cover**

and

> **house's door** or **house door**

Which one is right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Spain's prince" or "Spain's prince's"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/spains-prince-or-spains-princes)

Comment: @Chenmunka the question is different from the one quoted!

Comment: both are right, but prefer those *without the apostrophe*. That's how we practice. Because in other case, it looks *odd*. Consider - Manchester team football player over Manchester's team's football's player! :P

Comment: That's why its shortened to ManU's player... or were you thinking about City?

Comment: @Chenmunka Did you actually read both questions carefully? The "Spain's prince" is about the **multiple possessive** constructions, and this is about **possessive vs. noun adjunct.**

Answer (score 5):

They are both correct.

> **A book's cover is called a book cover**

**Book** in book cover acts more like an **adjective** describing **cover** just as

> **front** cover
>   **back** cover
>   **cloud** cover
>   **buggy** cover

these are saying what the **cover** is associated with.  It is possible the usage of **book's cover** changed to **book cover** sometime in the past.

Though they both refer to the same thing: the **dust jacket** of a book

> book's cover

emphasizes the **book**

> book cover

emphasizes the **cover**

Answer (score 2):

Peter has done a pretty good job explaining how this works.  As for the *why*, that's a trickier question.

In **X's Y**, **X's** is a *possessive*: the Y belongs to the X.
In **X Y**, **X** is a *[noun adjunct](http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/rules/nounadj.html)*: X acts like an adjective describing the Y.

[Here's a discussion of the difference on English.SE.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87591/a-noun-adjunct-the-possessive-case)

To give some examples of usage, I would say that **house's door** means "a door belonging to a house" while **house door** means "a door of the type *house*".  A door is only a *house's door* if it actually belongs to or is associated with a particular house, but it could be a *house door* even if it's never belonged to any house - for example, maybe it is at the hardware store waiting for someone to buy it and put it on their house.

Sometimes you can use either one:

> Approaching the scene of the explosion, he saw a car door lying in the middle of the street.

works just as well as

> Approaching the scene of the explosion, he saw a car's door lying in the middle of the street.

It works both ways because it was a door of the type 'car' and it was a door that had belonged (presumably) to a specific car.